# what is the meaning of hsv[...,1] = 255?

Tags: python, opencv

I was referring the open-cv dense optical-flow code and and I found the following :

```
hsv[...,1] = 255
```

What is the meaning of this?

Code : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/dee/tutorial_optical_flow.html

Comment: Does this answer your question: [use of ellipsis in modifying numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49340378/5431791)?

Comment: It makes all colours fully saturated. It sets the saturation in the HSV model to maximum.

Answer (score 1):

For the array `hsv` all values in the first column are set to 255. I believe open-cv took the syntax from numpy

```
hsv = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,5))
>>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,5, 4))
>>> arr
array([[[7, 7, 8, 3],
        [2, 7, 6, 6],
        [6, 8, 6, 6],
        [7, 5, 7, 6],
        [4, 1, 1, 7]],

       [[5, 4, 1, 0],
        [2, 2, 2, 0],
        [4, 4, 7, 4],
        [8, 5, 9, 3],
        [5, 6, 4, 7]],

       [[8, 6, 3, 3],
        [5, 4, 6, 4],
        [3, 4, 1, 9],
        [8, 0, 5, 4],
        [5, 0, 7, 6]]])
```

```
>>> arr[..., 1] = 255
>>> arr
array([[[  7, 255,   8,   3],
        [  2, 255,   6,   6],
        [  6, 255,   6,   6],
        [  7, 255,   7,   6],
        [  4, 255,   1,   7]],

       [[  5, 255,   1,   0],
        [  2, 255,   2,   0],
        [  4, 255,   7,   4],
        [  8, 255,   9,   3],
        [  5, 255,   4,   7]],

       [[  8, 255,   3,   3],
        [  5, 255,   6,   4],
        [  3, 255,   1,   9],
        [  8, 255,   5,   4],
        [  5, 255,   7,   6]]])
```

Comment: If we take this: hsv = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3,5,4)) output looks like this : [[[  4 255   8   9]
  [  9 255   9   0]
  [  0 255   0   5]
  [  1 255   1   9]
  [  1 255   4   6]]

 [[  8 255   4   1]
  [  0 255   1   3]
  [  3 255   8   8]
  [  6 255   8   3]
  [  4 255   3   4]]

 [[  7 255   1   4]
  [  8 255   1   5]
  [  3 255   3   0]
  [  2 255   8   2]
  [  4 255   4   6]]] can we genaralize it? As the colum value of the internal array?

Comment: updated to be more general